# Rendering an isometric grid

Tags: java, swing, isometric

I'm making a map editor for an isometric game, and I'm a bit stuck on rendering an isometric guide grid (a grid that shows where objects will be placed). That is, I need to draw lines across a Graphics object in such a way that it forms a grid with cells of variable width and height. What can I do to accomplish this?

So far I have:

```
//The number of cells in each direction
int nv=h/cellh;
int nh=w/cellw;
for(int i=1;i<=nv;++i){
    g.drawLine(0,i*cellh,i*cellh*2,0);
}
```

But that just draws bottom left to upper right lines that begin on the left side.

Comment: Draw your grid on paper, and use this to help figure out an algorithm for drawing the grid.

Comment: See also [*Mapping Screen to World Coordinates*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_graphics_in_video_games_and_pixel_art#Mapping_Screen_to_World_Coordinates).

Comment: Hovercraft, I already tried that.

Comment: It is a matter of logic. I don't really understand your for loop (or maybe I'm just tired) but I would do it like this: for(each row (or columns if you prefer) of cells) draw a line from the (x,y) of the first cell to the end point of the last cell. //You should have an array of cells, anyways.

Answer (score 3):

This will work as you expect:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    int sizeW = 50;
    int sizeH = 50;
    int countW = width / sizeW;
    int countH = height / sizeH;

    for (int i = 0; i <= countW + countH; i++) {
        g.drawLine(0, i * sizeH, i * sizeH, 0);
        g.drawLine(width - i * sizeW, 0, width, i * sizeW);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a normal grid :/ I need an isometric grid, namely with lines of slope 1/2 and -1/2 criscrossing across the Graphics object.

Comment: I've edited the answer to resemble "lines of slope 1/2 and -1/2" , as in the above comment.